# marshmallow-sqlalchemy Unable to get child model's data from parent model_schema

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I'm trying to use marshmallow-sqlalchemy to create an API

However, When I dump data, It shows only parent models data only

like {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-09-01'}

How do I get company data like {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-09-01', 'orders': {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-09-01'}, {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-09-01'}}

the model is

```
class Order(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    company_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user_company.id'), nullable=False)
    company = db.relationship('UserCompany', backref='orders', lazy=True)
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(), server_default=func.now())

class UserCompany(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    company_name = db.Column(db.String(length=20))
```

And the schema is

```
class OrderSchema(ModelSchema):
    class Meta:
        sqla_session = db.Session
        fields = ('id', 'date')
        model = Order


order_schema = OrderSchema()
orders_schema = OrderSchema(many=True)


class UserCompanySchema(ModelSchema):
    orders = Nested(OrderSchema, many=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'company_name')
        model = UserCompany
        sqla_session = db.session


user_company_schema = UserCompanySchema()
```

and the View is

```
company = UserCompany.query.get(current_user.company.id)
print(user_company_schema.dump(company))

{'id': 1, 'date': '2019-09-01'}
```

What I want is

```
{'id': 1, 'date': '2019-09-01', 'orders': {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-09-01'}, {'id': 1, 'date': '2019-09-01'}}
```

Comment: Looks like `user_company_schema` is in fact instance of `OrderSchema` with order instance passed. Are you sure all of the pasted code is what you meant?

Comment: @stasiekz I'm sorry, it was a mistake. I just updated UserCompanySchema and OrderSchema

Comment: use `class Meta(ModelSchema.Meta):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly set all of desired fields in Meta class if you want them to be present in dumps.

```
class UserCompanySchema(ModelSchema):
    orders = Nested(OrderSchema, many=True)
    class Meta:
        fields = ('id', 'company_name', 'orders')
        model = UserCompany
        sqla_session = db.session
```